# Как оптимизировать проверку условий в форме?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, оптимизировать код проверки условий на странице оформления заказа.

Есть страница оформления заказа, сделанная на конструкторе, который позволяет вставить кастомный html-css-js код.

Есть форма на PHP, которая принимает запросы, которые отправляются после первого входа на страницу заказа и возвращает информацию о пользователе из базы.

На основании этой информации делаются проверки.

Например, если вернулось hasDiagnostic === "true" и workedWith === "какая-то строка", то сделать следующие операции:

```
if (hasDiagnostic === "true") {

      if (workedWith !== undefined) {
        $(`option[value="${workedWith}"]`).attr("selected", "selected");
      }

      switch (workedWith) {
        case "Лилия":
          typeConsultation.prop("checked", true);
          typeConsultation.click();
          liliyaConsultation.prop("checked", true);
          liliyaConsultation.click();
          break;
        case "Александра":
          typeConsultation.prop("checked", true);
          typeConsultation.click();
          alexConsultation.prop("checked", true);
          alexConsultation.click();
          break;
```

Это лишь маленький участок кода, у меня там дальше по 15 таких "кейсов".

Это можно как-то оптимизировать или придётся мириться с огромным количеством кейсов и условий?

Или другой случай, более сложный для меня.

Нужно отслеживать изменение двух параметров, например: выбор имени специалиста и выбор типа услуги. Перед этим, естественно, скрипт запросил у базы данные о пользователе и вернул их.

И дальше начинается пляска:

1. (если выбран тип услуги №1 и сотрудник) И (значение из базы === имя сотрудника), то всё ок, ничего не делаем
2. (если выбран тип услуги №1 и сотрудник) И (значение из базы !== имя сотрудника), то выводим предупреждение
3. (если выбран тип услуги №2 и сотрудник) И (значение из базы === имя сотрудника и другое значение из базы === true), то всё ок, ничего не делаем

И так далее. Вот тут ступор, как это всё учитывать при проверке, если пользователь может свободно переключать типы услуг (там радио-кнопка) и выбирать сотрудника из выпадающего списка?

Делать большой список условий, который будет проверяться при изменении типа услуги? Типа input[id="type"].change() - и внутри погнал проверять все условия, если сменилась радио-кнопка.

И отдельно select[option="Имя Фамилия"].change() - это для КАЖДОГО сотрудника в списке - и тоже аналогичные проверки, только на совпадение с типом услуги?

Вроде простая проверка, по сути, но у меня всё на 200 строк кода выходит. Понимаю, что творю дикую вирмишель из кода, но как оптимизировать - не понимаю :(

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь идеи по оптимизации таких проверок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странная у вас последовательность.

- В чем сакральный смысл подобных записей "liliyaConsultation" "alexConsultation"? Уже на этапе их создания, вы должны были усомниться в правильности своего выбора. Когда появится новый врач Петя, вы будете код переписывать peterConsultation? Я уж не говорю про switch...
- У вас же есть бэк с БД, куда просто надо отправить корректные запросы и он выдаст вам нужные данные по врачам, по пациентам, зачем вы загружаете фронт бизнес логикой?
- Я бы на вашем месте сначала понял, какие данные можно получить с бека, и, как минимум, нарисовал бы подробную блок схему всего процесса.
- Хотите оптимизировать? Используйте state machine, а не "Если анализы сданы" "Если врач назначен", "Простыня из свитчкейсов)

Comment: 1)В чем сакральный смысл подобных записей
>Ввёл их для удобства. Это переменные, в которые вшито обращение к нужным элементам по их значению в Input

2)У вас же есть бэк с БД
>Там не совсем так. Если php-скрипт, который принимает запрос с фронта (значение имейла) и отправляет по АПИ запрос в другой сервис, получает ответ и возвращает его фронту. Как все эти условия и запросы скомпоновать, чтобы всё на бэке решалось - пока не пойму :(

Схема процесса в процессе, жаль, что спустя неделю работы.

3)Хотите оптимизировать? Используйте state machine
>Спасибо за совет, после схемы погуглю.

Comment: @АлександрТимощук я бы на вашем месте сначала про стейты почитал, т.к. это займет очень мало времени, а уже потом схему рисовал, т.к. сейчас вы хотите задачу целиком решить, а вам надо ее разбить на этапы. Условно: Назначение Диагностики -> Окончание диагностики/Выбор лечащего врача -> Назначение лечащего врача  Т.е., как миниму, у пациента есть 3 состояния, в каждом из которых делаются разные запросы к серверу.